# Finding IP addresses of all bitcoin miners

Tags: mining-pools, privacy, peers, peer-discovery

I understand that the transactions don't have any IP info in them but I am curious to know if it is possible to enumerate over list of all the IP addresses involved in mining?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. IP addresses are not part of the Bitcoin blockchain in any way whatsoever so this data is simply unavailable.

Comment: what if we simply do something like "netstat -an | grep -i established" and observe the connected peers ?

Comment: Your node is not connected to all peers in the network. Furthermore not all peers are mining peers.

Comment: @AndrewChow so how does [ViaBtc can knows this](https://www.viabtc.com/) (though I recognize it’s for ʙᴄʜᴀʙᴄ) ?

Comment: Block explorers display the IP address of the node that relayed them the transaction. It is not the IP address where the transaction originated.

Comment: @AndrewChow in that case, how to get the exact ɪᴘ address and how do they know for example that a specific ɪᴘ address of a node belongs to btc.com for example ?

Comment: ViaBTC's "relayed by" is not the IP address of the node that created the block or relayed them. That is saying who mined a block which is identified by self identifying data that miner's include in their blocks. That data can be faked and omitted which is why there are many blocks that are from "unknown" miners. IP addresses are completely unrelated to that.

Answer (score 0):

it Is  possible - You use shodan.io to search "Antminer" and you get all scanned antminers and their IPs.THe net thing to do is only brute force web based control pannel and swap a wallet address :-)