# Classifying Miners based on their Location

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, miner-configuration

Is there any way to classify the bitcoin miners based on their geographical locations?
Is there any possibility of doing so for the participants in cooperative mining as well?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to classify the bitcoin miners based on their geographical locations?

According to this answer it's not possible to check IP address of miners: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/66269

Even if it is possible with a workaround, they can use Tor, VPN, other proxy etc.

Non-KYC mining pools exist so miners do not share their real identity and location with pools. Even if they share such information, it can be faked and not necessary they have all the ASICs at one location.

Lot of journalists and researchers use other information and assumptions to speculate miners location. Example: https://coinshares.com/assets/resources/Research/bitcoin-mining-network-december-2019.pdf